# How to remove index.php from url in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp

I have tried commenting this line present in congif/core.php,
// Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
But when I hit my url it gives me 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are loading mod_rewrite correctly. You should see something like

```
#uncomment it by removing leading #

LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Verify that your .htaccess files are actually in the right directories. Some operating systems treat files that start with ‘.’ as hidden and therefore won’t copy them.

```
 #CAKEPHP root .htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

#Cakephp App directory .htacess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

#Cakephp webroot directory .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

[URL_REWRITING](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may fix it with your web-sersver ([.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) rules for apache, [rules](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) in configuration file for nginx).